# Node.JS - how to use sanitization in controller

Tags: node.js, express, validation

I have this function into a Node Controller:

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
exports.createService = ([
  body('section_title_en').trim().escape(),
  body('title_en').trim().escape()
], (req, res, next)) => { ....
```

An is used into a route

```
router.post('/add', ServiceController.createService);
```

The above code into controller is not JS valid code, my question is how can I use this sanitization into controller.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "not valid JS code"? It's far from clear if this is what you're doing, or what you're intending to do, or what you wish you could do.

Comment: I get error, is not a valid js syntax...

Comment: Yeah, well, it isn't. That's an array with...some stuff just sort of stapled on the end. You're going to have to explain what `body` is, and why this can't be as simple as `function createService(req, res, next) { ... }` that's later exported.

Comment: I add validator import, check question again, thanks.

Comment: Are you basically saying "I need to run those two operations" and nothing more? That's an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to create a wrapper that calls those functions, then you can do this:

```
// body_trim.js
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = [
  body('section_title_en').trim().escape(),
  body('title_en').trim().escape()
];
```

Where you can then use it like:

```
const bodyTrim = require('./body_trim');

router.post('/add', bodyTrim);
```

The hitch is that the `post()` function can take an array argument plus additional arguments, but you can only export one thing at a time, an array *or* a function, per property.

Comment: I'm just going off [the example code](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). If `bodyTrim` comes out as an array this should work according to the docs...